# Custom PHP Global Functions available across a server

Tags: php, function

I am familiar with built in php functions such as str_rev, str_replace, etc... Is there a way to enable our own custom functions to be automatically to a php document instead of being forced to use include or require?

In other words, I would like to make my own custom built-in like functions that can be called without having to include or require a file prior to function call. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, I don't consider global functions a good idea, however, yes, you can create a file, anywhere on your server and included in the `php.ini` file like so:

```
auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/global_functions.php"
```

Your `php.ini` will most probably already have the `auto_prepend_file` property so you may need to locate it and avoid having duplicate properties.

Comment: Thank you for your help!